# ¿Por qué no funciona la destructuración de array cuando se guarda en una variable pero sí cuando se usa console.log()?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando obtener los valores de un array como este:

```
contactos = [  
    [ { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] } ], 
    [ {persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] } ] 
]
```

para obtener lo siguiente:

```
contactos = [ 
    { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] }, 
    { persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] }
]
```

He intentado hacerlo con un ciclo `for` y `push`, con `flat` y con propagación (`...contactos`) y todos funcionan cuando uso `console.log()`, pero si almaceno los resultados en otra variable me sigue dando exactamente lo mismo que el array original. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Mi código:

Opción 1:
Si uso `console.log` para mostrar *contactos[i]* lo muestra correctamente, pero si uso `console.log` para mostrar *contactos2* me da el mismo array original.

```
let contactos2 = []

for(let i=0;  i < contactos.length; i++) {
    contactos2.push( contactos[i] );
}

console.log(contactos2);
```

Opción 2:
al usar `console.log(contactos2)` me imprime el mismo resultado que el array original

```
let contactos2 = contactos.flat(1);
console.log(contactos2);
```

Opción 3:
si uso: `console.log(...contactos)` me da el resultado esperado, pero si uso el siguiente código, me muestra el resultado original:

```
let contactos2 = [...contactos]
console.log(contactos2);
```

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: ¿Podrías acomodar el primer código?

Comment: @Mateo ¿acomodar? lo edité porque lo tenía mal, en .push usaba corchetes en lugar de paréntesis, ya lo cambié. muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si, la idea era que acomodes el espacio y de paso corrijas errores que probablemente tu código no tenga. Por cierto, no te falta una coma en el código del principio?

Comment: La opción 3, sería lo mismo que hacer `console.log([...contactos]);`... Sin embargo, al hacer `console.log(...contactos)` no tienes el resultado esperado ya que solo te devuelve los elementos dentro del subarray de `contactos` sueltos... esto sucede porque sólo lo desestructuras y no los almacenas en un arreglo vacío...

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la función [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). ¡Un saludo!

```js
const arr1 = [
  [{
    persona1: 'juan',
    num: ['333333']
  }],
  [{
    persona2: 'maría',
    num: ['888888']
  }]
];

const result = arr1.flatMap((item) => item);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Luego de agregar una coma para separar los elementos del arreglo y usar `flat` obtengo un resultado como el que esperas.

```js
contactos = [  
[ { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] } ],
[ {persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] } ] 
]

console.log(contactos.flat())
```

---

En cuanto a la segunda opción, ignorando que falta la llave de cierre, es imposible que produzca el resultado esperado.

Acceder a un elemento y `push` podría decirse que son operaciones *inversas*.

Al agregar cada uno de los elementos de un arreglo a otro arreglo obtienes una copia del mismo.

Cada uno de los elementos es un arreglo con un elemento, así que debes agregar el primer elemento de cada arreglo. ¡Qué embrollo!

En código se ve más fácil:

```js
contactos = [  
[ { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] } ],
[ {persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] } ] 
]

let contactos2 = []
for(let i=0; i < contactos.length; i++)
    contactos2.push(contactos[i][0]) 

// También puedes hacerlo con map
// contactos2 = contactos.map(c => c[0])
console.log(contactos2)
```

Comment: en la consola me muestra el array sin la coma entre los elementos y cuando intento la opción que me comentas, me dice que (contactos[i][0])  es undefined.

Comment: @Votan probaste el código? Yo no veo `undefined`. Que extraño.

Answer (score 0):

**Opción 1:**

Tu creas un nuevo array y a ese array le agregas los mismos elementos del original, evidentemente van a quedar iguales. Lo que tu quieres es generar un array distinto (eliminando un array interno que sobra)

Para ello tienes que ir a la posición cero del array interno

```js
const contactos = [[ { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] }], 
[ {persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] } ] ];

let contactos2 = [];
for(let i=0;  i < contactos.length; i++){
   
   //             Esto Falta----v
   contactos2.push(contactos[i][0]);
}                               

console.log(contactos2);
```

---

**Opción 2:**
Yo no veo problema en esto, y es realmente la opción a usar...para eso está la función `flat()`

```js
const contactos = [[ { persona1: 'juan', num: [ '333333' ] }], 
[ {persona2: 'maría', num: [ '888888' ] } ] ];

let contactos3 = contactos.flat(1); //simplemente contactos.flat()
console.log(contactos3);
```

---

**Opción 3**

Acá veo que no entiendes lo que hace el Spread. Este operado descompone un array (un iterable realmente) en partes separadas por coma. Cada parte no es un objeto (o elemento) valido. Por ejemplo, esto no se puede hacer:

```
const contactos4= ...contactos; //NO valido
```

Digamos que tenemos el siguiente array `const numeros=[1,2,3,4]`, si hacemos:

```
const NUMS = ...numeros;
//es lo mismo que haber escrito
const NUMS = 1,2,3,4; //Esto no es correcto, no tiene un formato valido
```

Otro ejemplo, `Math.min(valor1, valor2, valor3, ..etc)` retorna el minino de una series de números ingresados como argumentos

```js
const result = Math.min(1,2,3,4);
console.log(result);
```

¿Y si nuestros datos estuvieran en un array ?

```js
const numeros = [1,2,3,4];
const result = Math.min(numeros);
console.log(result); //NaN
```

Da como resultado `NaN`, pero aquí es donde viene el Spread al rescate

```js
const numeros = [1,2,3,4];
const result = Math.min(...numeros);
console.log(result); //1
```

Esto es justamente lo que pasa cuando haces `console.log(...contactos)`, porque `console.log` al igual que `Math.min` aceptan una cantidad variable de argumentos, es decir la sintaxis es `console.log(valor1,valor2,valor3,etc..)`. Y cuando lo imprime por consola **no muestra la coma**

```js
console.log(1,2,3,4);
```

Entonces NO es que `console.log(...contactos)` te de el resultado esperado, es una ilusión óptica, solo estas imprimiendo uno a uno los elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Cualquier cosa que declares como un array y quieras llenarlo iterando soble el objeto original terminará rodeado de tu array inicial.

Si a eso agregamos que no puedes destructurar el array "pelado"la opción que queda es mapear obteniendo el elemento 0 de cada elemento del array. Sin embargo esto es una solución precaria ya que no puedes contar con que cada eleeto tenga un solo item.

Sin saber el contenido del array pero sí su estructura general, podrías salirte con la tuya usando un reduce:

```js
contactos = [
  [{
    persona1: 'juan',
    num: ['333333']
  }, {
    persona1: 'pedro',
    num: ['22']
  }],
  [{
    persona2: 'maría',
    num: ['888888']
  }]
]

const flattened = contactos.reduce((accum, row) => {
  return accum.concat(...row);
}, []);

console.log(flattened);
```

Answer (score 0):

En la opción 1 obtienes el mismo resultado debido a que estas contruyendo nuevamente un arreglo de arreglo porque metes el i-ésimo elemento de contacto (que tambien es un arreglo).
Una posible solucion para esa opción es ingresar el primero elemento de cada entrada en el for

```
for(let i=0;  i < contactos.length; i++) {
  contactos2.push( contactos[i][0]);
}
```

Para que ello funcione, debes tener presente que solo introducirá el primero elemento de cada subarreglo.